# How to implement Vision API with 'Service account' in the iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to implement Google Vision API for the my app via REST. 
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf

Is there any examples or any suggestions how to do this?

Documentation says that they require service account token but can't find any examples how to get service account token from iOS app side.
I've tried via GTMAppAuth but getting 403 error

I was able to generate this token from my mac machine and all worked, but token has limited life time and after 3-4 hours it expiries

Comment: I need to take a look on the Vision API... I will write you a class with some example code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out and did this by my own.
Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth

1)You need to create service account, download p12 or JSON file. JSON file contains private key and public certificate url. You need to create text file, where private key on the top, certificate on the bottom and run this command:
openssl pkcs12 -export -in file_name.txt -out file_name.p12

2)Create jwt token with parameters which described in the documentation (for jwt I used this library: https://github.com/yourkarma/JWT)

3) Make POST request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token with parameters which described in the documentation

Hope it will help somebody in the future

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get a Bearer Token... You can get it by following the instructions on this page...

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth#using_an_api_key

The Bearer Token will not expire, you can implemented it to your code...

A Basic Version on how to add a Bearer Token to your Request in Swift is Shown below... All other Stuff goes as a JSON in Data Format to the "body" parameter

This Link will show you how to build up the JSON for your request to Vision... https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/using-curl

```
class APIHandler {

    private let API_TOKEN = "Your Token"

    func requestVisionFromREST(body: Data, completion: @escaping (_ response: Data?)-> Void)  {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        var headers = [String:String]()
        headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer \(API_TOKEN)"
        config.httpAdditionalHeaders = headers

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "YOUR URL")!)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.httpBody = body

        URLSession(configuration: config).dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            completion(data)
        }.resume()
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use the Google Sign In instead of the OAuth Method, to reauth your apps and get a fresh token, you can follow the instructions on the googles instructions page below:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access

Comment: I've done similar but after 3-4 hours token become expired and I'm getting 401 error from the vision API

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys?hl=de&ref_topic=6262490&visit_id=636814259911996131-2934757354&rd=1

Comment: Google says that if you create a new Token, the old one will expire after 24 hours... Thats the only part on their site where I see that the token may expire... I am working on many projects with Google API Tokens, like Maps, and Android Apps and their tokens didn't expire on any project... Did may accidentally refresh the token?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth
according to documentation service account token has only 1 hour life time

Comment: Well yes I did never see this possibility before... I always use their OAut tokens... Well then you need to Reauth after a token did expire... I will take a look if I see the Swift way of doing this, or I will write you one and update my answer...

Comment: Or take a look at his links, are you able to solve it with the Google Sign In yourself?

Comment: Google Sign isn't the best way, because in this case I'm getting 403 error, since user doesn't have access to the data base